# Redirect to home.php if $_GET['id'] is invalid or empty

Tags: php

I want to redirect the user if $_GET['id'] is empty or if the user with that id is not found, can anyone provide a simple example?

Comment: Have you tried any thing to achieve that?

Comment: `if (empty($_GET['id']) || $countUserWithThisID > 0) { header("Location: /index.php"); exit; }` -- this code has to be executed before any output, as that's a requirement for `header()` functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PHP's `empty()` to check if the it's empty.

```
if(empty($_GET['id']) {
    header("Location: page.php");
    exit;
} else
    // not empty
}
```

As from the literal meaning `empty()` means variable is empty. It's a BOOL function, which means that it will return `true` when empty and `false` when not empty.

Also, remember to use `exit` after `header` as the PHP script will not stop executing unless `exit` is stated.

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for both conditions to be fulfilled, but I think you can encapsulate all the checks in one function.

```
/**
 * Checks if a user id is valid and user exists
 * @param integer $id
 * @return boolean
 */               
public function validate_user($id){
    // always validate whatever input you get from users
    $valid_id = filter_var($id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    if ($valid_id){
        // check if the user_id is a valid user against your APP logic
        return USER::getUser($valid_id);
    }
    return false;
}


if(!validate_user($_GET['id'])){
    header('Location:home.php');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use the function `empty` ([documentation here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)) because it checks other cases, not only empty strings. If is a simple check, you don't need to use braces eather, put this at the beginning of your file and it should work.

```
if(empty($_GET['id'])) {
    header('Location:index.php');
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple example. For redirecting you can use the php 'header()'funciton. Hope this helps.

```
if($_GET['id']==''){
    header('Location:somepage.php');
    }
```

Comment: Using `empty()` is better, because you can get *Undefined index* with the code you have. Also, using `exit;` after `header("Location ...");` is a good idea.

Comment: yes you're right that the empty function is better in most cases, but I wanted to show a very very simple way because from the question you can see that the questioner is a beginner so I tried to give him a simple and understandable answer. But thanks for your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

If it's empty you can use answer from DevMan.

And if there is no id in the database than you can set query, create variable $find = 0, and use while loop to go through the table and check if $_GET['id'] == $id(that's the id from the database).

If they match than $find++ if not it will stay 0.

```
if($find == 0){
   header('Location:somepage.php');
}
```

If you want both first check if it's empty(as DevMan posted) and than if there is that id in the database as i posted.